# error downloading wine32 on kali linux - 'Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate'

Tags: linux, installation, terminal, kali-linux, wine

```
\\the command I wrote:
root@kali:~# apt-get install wine32
\\what I got:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine32 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate

I tried adding to /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

then tried again to install and still had the same error(using 'apt-get install wine32')

I also tried using 'dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32'

Comment: First thing to do : `apt-cache search wine` .... to decide a package name. .... Kali : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following three into `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali​ kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali​ sana main non-free contrib
deb http://old.kali.org/kali​ moto main non-free contrib
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

Refer to the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP4LUpkUyKA

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

into `/etc/apt/sources.list`; then,

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

It should work.

Comment: I don't think this adds anything that wasn't already posted in the other answer. Are you sure you need sources and regular `deb` entry isn't enough?